# How to make setSignatureAppearance() location to be dynamic depending on the page content?

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I am trying to add the setSignatureAppearance() in a pdf generated using tcpdf. But the signature is stucka t one place whereas I want it to be dynamically moving along with the signature image as the data in my pdf is totally dynamic.

I called the setSignatureAppearance() and passed the height and width values after matching it with the image "sign2.png" which I have added in the  tag. But if data increases, the image moves down with data ad signature appearance stays at the same place where it was previously. I want it to move along with the image.

```
$html.="<td colspan=\"4\" nowrap style=\"text-align: center;border: 1px solid black\">
<b>For B4U Broadband (India) Pvt. Ltd.</b>
<br /><br /><br/>
<div id="digitalSignature">
<img src="C:/Apache24/htdocs/rapid/sign2.png" class="center" width="190" height="85">
</div>
</td> 
</tr>";
$html.="</table>";
}
$html = utf8_decode($html);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->setSignatureAppearance(110, 217, 90, 50,$page = -1);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('Invoice.pdf', 'I');
```

The signature appearance should dynamically move along with the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the setSignatureAppearance(x,y,w,h) values based on page height(Y)/page margins/desired content, then use writeHtmlCell to write something (eg signature details) at the same positions.

```php
<?php
    $pdf->writeHTML($html);

    $getMargins = $pdf->getMargins();
    $pageWidth = $pdf->getPageWidth();
    $lMargin = $getMargins['left'];
    $rMargin = $getMargins['right'];

    $pdf->SetFontSize(7);
    $pdf->setSignatureAppearance($x = $lMargin, $y = $pdf->GetY()-8, $w = ($pageWidth - $lMargin - $rMargin)/2, $h = 10, -1, 'signature_for_provider');
    $pdf->setAlpha(0.5,'Normal');
    $pdf->Image('AdobeDS.png',$x+3.5,$y,0,$h);
    $pdf->setAlpha(1,'Normal');
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html_cell = '<blockquote>Digitally signed by '.$CN.' <br/>DN: '.$DN.'<br/>Date: '.$SigningTime.'</blockquote>', $border = 0, $ln = 0, $fill = 0);

?>
```